# How do you build a modular/ composite SOA based webapp?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, backbone.js, soa

I am working on breaking a massive monolithic Rails website into smaller ones in order to reduce complexity, allow for independent updates, and all the other SOA goodness. What I would like is to have each "embedded" site to present its own UI, along with any other assets it may need as dependencies. So far the twitter widgets and google ads have been interesting examples as they provide distinct functionality via a s script tag.

Specific questions I have:
 - How do you effectively sandbox each app? One may use a different version of jQuery or Backbone then the other?
 - What tools have you used to accomplish something like?
 - Any apps I should look into of inspiration?

Answer (score 1):

I like the way that [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/) explains composite apps and SOA.  So I would recommend watching [this talk](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/design-architecture/talk-from-udi-dahan) to start with.

Comment: This is a great talk that I think more people considering SOA should watch. Basically - the idea is that a UI is composed from the data of many services. You can use something like Backbone or jQuery to make AJAX calls to each service and then compose the UI in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I've created project showing how to build Composite UI web app in soa system - it's implemented in asp.net mvc, but the idea itself can be used in other technologies.
Link:

> https://github.com/padzikm/CompositeUI

In this approach every service has its own web app component, which is responsible for delivering widgets to client and for handling client activities (for example form sending). Next all web app's are integrated in transparent way into one web application, so at the end you have one web application that is responsible for handling client requests. In this way, each service web app works inside its service boundaries, not knowing about any other services and there is no integration component between these applications, so all components can be develop independently.